# Bean is not enhanced?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

If I try to run my project, via `Intellij` or `terminal`, my application works fine. However, when I tried to run only my `tests`, they break with the following exception:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Project is not enhanced?
...


2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Project is not enhanced?
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
```

I think it might be something with how my project setup. However, I don't have any idea of what might be.

This is my [build.sbt](https://github.com/valterhenrique/ddrop/blob/master/build.sbt), [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/valterhenrique/ddrop/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt), and [application.conf](https://github.com/valterhenrique/ddrop/blob/master/conf/application.conf).

The strange think is that, if I start my application normally, and run my tests, they work, but I need to stop/start my application every time that I need to run my tests,and this is annoying :)

Any idea, or suggestion would be very much appreciate!

Comment: For me the solution was, to use JDK 8 instead of JDK 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for those who might have the same problem as I had. If you're using IntelliJ, go to `Settings`, `Plugins` and type `Ebean`, several options will show it to you. I chose the `Ebean 4x Enhancement` option, install it and restart Intellij. Now, go to `Build` and make sure that 'Ebean 4x Enhancement' is enabled. Now you can run your tests with Intellij!

Comment: This works for me, thanks!  BTW, what does this "enhance" mean? , at last.

Comment: don't forget to rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

A more complete answer based on Valter Silva one as I had to search a bit and kept having the error after installation as I did not activate the plugin in Build menu:

1. `Settings` -> `Plugins`
2. Search for `EBean`
3. If not found click on "`Search in Repositories`"
4. Install "`Ebean yy.x Enhancement`" version corresponding to your project (4.x, 10.x, 11.x...)
5. Restart Intelij
6. Activate (thick) `Build` -> "`Ebean yy.x+ Enhancement`"
7. Rebuild project
8. Run your tests

Comment: How do you know which version is the good one?

Comment: Use the version set in your project dependencies